# Opencv bf.knnmatch assertion failed

Tags: python, opencv

What am I missing, I am getting this error. Without bruteforce matcher I can see the keypoints. But when I am trying to match them using BF I am getting this error.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('2.mp4')
imgt = cv2.imread('a.png')
imgp = cv2.imread('down.jpg')
hT,wT,cT = imgt.shape
imgvideo = cv2.resize(imgp,(wT,hT))
orb = cv2.ORB_create(nfeatures=1000)
kp1, desp1 = orb.detectAndCompute(imgt,None)
imgt = cv2.drawKeypoints(imgt,kp1,None)

while (cap.isOpened()):

    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    #frame = cv2.resize(frame, (540, 380), fx=0, fy=0,
     #                  interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    kp2, desp2 = orb.detectAndCompute(frame, None)
    #frame = cv2.drawKeypoints(frame, kp2, None)
    bf = cv2.BFMatcher()
    matches = bf.knnMatch(desp1,desp2,k=2)
    good =[]
    for m,n in matches:
        if m.distance < 0.75 *n.distance:
            good.append(m)
    print(len(good))

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('Frame', frame)
    cv2.imshow('imagetarget', imgt)
    cv2.imshow('imagetarget2', imgvideo)


    # define q as the exit button
    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# release the video capture object
cap.release()
# Closes all the windows currently opened.
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Error

```
 error: (-215:Assertion failed) type == src2.type() && src1.cols == src2.cols && (type == CV_32F || type == CV_8U) in function 'cv::batchDistance'
```